# Custom Theme: The active theme is broken. Reverting to the default theme

Tags: theme-development

I'm making my own theme and I just got this message while trying to activate my theme: "The active theme is broken. Reverting to the default theme." Live preview works, but when I select this theme it reverts back to a new theme. I have index.php and my style.css files set up as I was using this theme fine before. I've disabled all plugins and even tried a fresh copy of wordpress.

Is there any way to troubleshoot this issue and see what in my theme is breaking?

Comment: Check the style.css -> https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/basics/main-stylesheet-style-css/

Comment: The comment at the top of `style.css` is not optional, and some of the components of it are required, without seeing the top of your `style.css` it's not possible to tell

Comment: I have the same problem, but I am not even able to see the style.css sheet

Answer (score 1):

You need to add some compulsary code in top of the `style.css` file

just copy and paste this commented code you can change theme name as per your requirement.

https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/basics/main-stylesheet-style-css/#example

```
/*
Theme Name: Twenty Seventeen

Theme URI: https://wordpress.org/themes/twentyseventeen/

Author: the WordPress team

Author URI: https://wordpress.org/

Description: Twenty Seventeen 

Version: 1.0

License: GNU General Public License v2 or later

License URI: http://www.gnu.org/licenses/gpl-2.0.html

Text Domain: twentyseventeen

Tags: one-column, two-columns

*/
```